# How to add any View (Button, TextView, Spinner) as a menu item to ActionBar using Java in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to add any **View** such as **Button**, **TextView** or **Spinner** to my ***ActionBar***.

How can I achieve this?

An example containing any of the **Views** will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add view in actionbar, you can use toolbar and you can add view in toolbar. For example;

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            // Add whatever you want

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I can use **Toolbar**. But my question was about doing it using **ActionBar**.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing an example of ***ActionBar*** containing a **Button**:

At first, we need to design the **menu_button.xml** to **res/layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAllCaps="false"/>
```

Next, we need to add **button_background.xml** to **res/drawable**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="#4796F6"/>

    <padding
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:top="7dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1.5dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

After that, we need to add **menu.xml** to **res/menu**: (*In this menu we are going to add our **Button** we designed in **menu_button.xml***)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_button" />

</menu>
```

At last, from **java file** we will get the **menu item as Button** and print a **Toast** on clicking it.

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        final MenuItem itemButton = menu.findItem(R.id.button);
        button = (Button) itemButton.getActionView();
        button.setText("ActionBar Button");

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // do your action here
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ActionBar Button was pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return true;

    }

}
```